# Is this sentence grammatically correct-"Which they call evil, might be motivation for many"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct-**"Which they call evil, might be motivation for many"**?

Comment: "that which" or "what" are more usual in place of "which", although I've a feeling you might find "which" used in some old or archaic texts.

Answer (score 1):

Original:  Which they call evil, might be motivation for many”?  (bad grammar)

"Which" is a relative pronoun that must be tied to a noun (a subject in this case, which is missing).  Add "that" (pronoun) as a subject.

=> That [which they call evil] might be motivation for many.

(Essentially, "that might be motivation for many", where we have previously mentioned "evil".)